# Дайте шаблон цикла for (c++)

Tags: c++, for

мне нужно написать цикл, который прибавляет к переменной i, в которой содержится 1 до те пор, пока число не дойдет до 10

Comment: и в чем у вас проблемы? прочитайте про циклы `for`, `while`, `do while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
  //Body
}
```

Comment: Если число 10 должно включаться, то i <= 10, соответственно

Comment: спасибо, а зачем //body?

Comment: Тело цикла, просто написал комментарий,  что вместо него какой-то код (тело - агл. Body) цикла